# AngularFire $createUser 's promise doesn't return an object containing user data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-service, angularfire

According to the documentation the $createUser function, "... returns a promise that is resolved with an object containing user data about the created user"

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-createusercredentials

When I use the function (see code below), I can register the user sucessfully but when I read the variable that should contain the UID, it's not defined.

In Chrome's console I get: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined"

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be retrieving the value differently?

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL, $location, $rootScope) {
// using $firebaseAuth instead of SimpleLogin 

var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

var myObject = {
    login : function(user) {
        console.log('authentication.js: logging in')
        return authObj.$authWithPassword({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        });
    }, //login

    logout : function(){
        return authObj.$unauth();
    }, // logout 

    register : function(user) {
        console.log('authentication.js: registering user')
        return authObj.$createUser({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }).then( function(userData) {
            console.log("User " + userData.uid + " created successfully!");
        });
    } // register

} //myObject

return myObject;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an old version of Firebase. I was using version 2.0.4 and according to this post https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/507 , to get the user object from the promise you need Firebase 2.0.5 or later and AngularFire 0.9.1 or later.

Using these CDN's now everything is working correctly.

```
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.5/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```